# Rendering dynamically generated HTML through pyramid Response

Tags: python, pyramid, python-2.6, python-2.7, python-2.x

I am new to python's pyramid framework so kindly help me.

I have a HTML dynamically generated. This HTML is generated by a python script which dynamically writes (tags/tables) which are extracted from some 'xyz.html' [using beautifulsoup] to another 'abc.html'.

Now i need to send this html page ('abc.html') back as a 'Response' object of 'pyramid.response' .

how can i do this. I tried the following

```
    _resp = Response()
    _resp.headerlist =  [('Content-type',"text/html; charset=UTF-8'"\]
    _resp.app_iter = open('abc.html','r')
    return _resp
```

and also

```
   with open('abc.html','r') as f:
      data = f.read()
      f.close()
   return Response(data,content_type='text/html')
```

both did not work.

PS: I cannot use renderer="package:subpack/abc.html" or any similar renderer as this generated html is stored in a dynamically generated location everytime so i cannot guess the final storage location of this html file.

Thanks in advance for you help.

Comment: It would be good to specify how your two attempts did not work.

Comment: ValueError: Could not convert view return value "{}" into a response object. This is the error i have been facing. I can provide the complete traceback too if it will help. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a little surprised your first example doesn't work. Check out this cookbook entry on it from the Pyramid docs and see if that helps.

http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid_cookbook/en/latest/static_assets/files.html#serving-file-content-dynamically

Comment: ValueError: Could not convert view return value "{}" into a response object

Comment: This is the error i am facing. And i also tried Michale's what was given in michale's link even that gave me the same error as above.

Comment: Also the storage location of the html generated is like this 'home/user/Pyenv/some_dir/new_dir/abc.html' where the 'new_dir' is a new sub directory created on every run and this location is not under my python project.